# jquery datatables not working on JSF

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, datatables

How can I apply [jquery datatable](http://datatables.net/) on JSF datatables ?

The following not working , because id on jsf datatable (i.e `<h:datatable id="example"...`) becomes `j_idt6:example` on html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
    </script>
```

any solution ?

Note: I am using because of client pagination and search.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 <h:datatable id="example"...
```

to

```
 <h:datatable styleClass="example"...
```

Then just use `$('.example').dataTable();`

Comment: In jsf there is no `class` attribute, instead use `styleClass` (which will be translated to html class later on)

Answer (score 0):

you may wrap the table into the form, and then the id fill be formID:tableID

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with JSF, you should consider using the [PrimeFaces Library , they got a really great table component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf)

If you still want to go with the really great datatables plugin here are several solutions:

1) Add `prependId="false"` to your `h:form` , that way you wont get that id with form prefix

2) Set an id to your `h:form` and use the following jquery code `$('#myForm\\:example').dataTable();`

3) Call the `dataTable` constructor on `styleClass="example"` attribute of the table instead of the `id`

---

Also, you can try out my [Yet Another DataTables Column Filter (Yadcf)](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html)